# How to use a global variable with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have a code as shown below.

```
var globalVar = ''
$.get("some.php", function(data, status)
{
    alert(data)
    globalVar = data
});
alert(globalVar)
```

While the first alert shows the value of data, the second alert doesn't. It seems like globalVar was not properly assigned inside the get's function. What would be the proper way to use a global variable here?

Comment: This has more to do with asynchronous aspects of "ajax" instead of variable scope.  It's most likely that the second alert is called before the get is finished.

Comment: Yes, you are right :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What probably happens is that your `get()` function doesn't finish before your last `alert()` is being called. To make sure these happen in order, you can put the last `alert()` in a callback once the file is received.

So try this instead:

```
 var globalVar = ''
 $.get("some.php", function(data, status)
 {
   alert(data)
   globalVar = data
 }).done(function() {
   alert(globalVar)
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var globalVar = false;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'some.php',
    success: function (data) {
    globalVar = true;
    }, 
    async: false // <- this turns it into synchronous
});​

alert(globalVar);
```

---

I update the better way in this case

```
var globalVar = false;

function getData(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'jsOnChange.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: callback
    })
}
getData(function(response) {
    globalVar = true;
    console.log(globalVar);
});
```

Comment: Synchronous AJAX requests are the worst idea to suggest.

Comment: If you have any better idea please let me know and learn it. xD After voted down my answer xD Thanks

Comment: See the duplicate target above.